# onActivityResult does not get the result

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have an android activity which starts another to get a result. The second Activity has a custom listview which should return a value based on the selection to the parent Activity. The problem is that in onActivityResult I will get a RESULT_OK=-1 but my returned value is always 0; 
in the first Activity, I call the second in an optionsMenu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE );
            return false;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

my onActivityResult is:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        workTime = i.getIntExtra("workTime", 0);            
    }
}
```

And in second Activity:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Profile selected = (Profile) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),  MainActivity.class);
            long w = selected.getWorkTime; //has the correct value.
            i.putExtra("workTime", w);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/103/intent#t=201612310854047774161)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was that I sent a `long` in the intent but requested to get an `int` in the `onActivityResult`, so  I needed to define `workTime` as a `long` and the `onActivityResult` should be:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
    workTime = i.getLongExtra("workTime", 0);            
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your Second Activity, just use this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Profile selected = (Profile) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            long w = selected.getWorkTime; //has the correct value.
            i.putExtra("workTime", w);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And in First Activity in onActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
       workTime = (int)i.getLongExtra("workTime", 0);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your understanding. The `RESULT_OK` value is `-1`, it is not `0`. So your `result` code is `-1`.
[Check this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOi0.png)